A movie about relationship between a young man and a middle aged woman
I'm looking for a 2000's movie that a young man who stays with a family in Switzerland to both earn money and advance his language skills. It was an European made movie probably French and made in between 2003-2012. The movie took place in just one city; Bern, Geneva or Zurich. 
The young man is aged between 18-20, had curly black hair, skinny and had medium height. I couldn't remember his nationality. The family had a little baby, about 3-6 months and he was babysitting him. The baby was very pretty and had big blue eyes. He was also doing the shopping, laundry and some other stuff when the parents at work. 
Their neighbour was a single lady. She was between 38-45, medium sized, had brown hair and fit for her age. She told the boy to call her anytime when he needed help. One day she seduced him and they had sex. It was the first time for the boy. He was very excited and told the details to the baby when they were outside. It happened couple of more times. 
I couldn't watch the rest...

Sounds like Jeune homme (2006)

An 18 years old man is leaving his Swiss German parent's house to learn 1 year French in Geneva, as au pair helper of this family. He learns there the easy and hard times of life and love.




